# Can't open spyder in windows 10 in a new environment

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, psutil

I creat a new environment by anaconda,but when I want to launch spyder,I meet the below problem. Who can help me?

`(sae) C:\Users\limin>spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\limin\Anaconda3\envs\sae\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import spyder.app.start
  File "C:\Users\limin\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 23, in <module>
    from spyder.utils.external import lockfile
  File "C:\Users\limin\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\external\lockfile.py", line 22, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "C:\Users\limin\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    from . import _pswindows as _psplatform
  File "C:\Users\limin\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_windows as cext
ImportError: cannot import name _psutil_windows`

Comment: Do you have your root environment in your PYTHONPATH? I say it because (according) Spyder is trying to import everything from root instead of your `sae` environment.

Comment: Yes,I do.I can open python2.7 by cmd

Comment: *Yes,I do*: Then that's the problem. Please remove your root environment from PYTHONPATH and use activate/deactivate when you want to use Python 2 in a terminal.